# Excel Graphs in Different Worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to reduce the amount of mechanical work I need to do in an Excel Document. It has 13 worksheets, one for every month + one which sums up the whole year. There is some data and some graphs in every worksheet. I want to make a graph that takes in two columns and draws them. Then I want to copy the graph and paste it on the next page where it will take data from the same columns. The problem is that when I create a graph it writes the following range

```
='02.2016 Д2'!$A$2:$A$30,'02.2016 Д2'!$C$2:$C$30
```

so when I copy it onto the next worksheet, it still uses the data from the previous worksheet. I'd go around and fix them one by one but there are 13 worksheets * 8 graphs and I'm inclined to believe that there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

First the bad news: **you can't use relative referencing in Excel charts.**
They have to point a particular sheet and have '$' everywhere.

The best idea is to **copy sheets instead of charts**. If a chart is pointing data in the same sheet, Excel will adjust the reference. Then you only have to put the proper data in each sheet.

I do things like that daily, and IMO the optimal workflow is:

1) Create your desired sheet for a single month.

2) Parametrize everything sheet-dependent and put the data in a separate sheet. The idea is to manually change only 1 cell in each sheet*.

3) Copy sheet and change the parameter.
The end. :)

This is also in line with proper sheet design: separated data and analysis, with the former in the most compressed form possible (e.g. single table for everything :)).

*) You can actually use the sheet's name, but it's usually not recommended.

---

If for whatever reason the above solution is unacceptable, you can replace source references in sheets using VBA. The instruction is simple:

```
refChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1:C4")
```

Looping through chosen sheets and assigning proper ranges could be tricky, though.